# items does not add to mySQL Table

Tags: mysql, reactjs

Do you know why I can not manually add the value "Sasan" to mySQL server?
MarioDB is installed in PHPStorm and schema is correctly selcted.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mysql =  require("mysql");
const cors = require("cors");

const db = mysql.createPool({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "Test123456",
    database: "shoppingList-DB"
});



app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.get("/test", (req, res) => {
    const sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO shoppingList (itemList) VALUES ('Sasan')";
    db.query(sqlInsert, (error, result) => {
        console.log("error", error);
        console.log("result", result)
        res.send("Hello Express");

    })

})

app.listen(5001, () =>{
    console.log("Server is up - Port 5001");
})
```

[image]

Comment: seems like there is some issue in database connectivity. Try connect with mysql using terminal

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty clear `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'`. Check your credentials and user access in `mysql.user` table.